PythonでYouTubeの動画を自動アップロードをしたいが、スケジュールの設定がうまくいかない
PythonとSeleniumでYouTubeに動画を自動アップロードするスクリプトを記述していますが、要素をうまく取得できません。
取得できない画面はこちらの画面で、「２０２４/１１/０５」の要素の部分です。よろしくお願いいたします。


タイトルの「スケジュールの設定がうまくいかない」と本文中の「要素をうまく取得できません。」で記述が違うのは何故でしょう？ どちらかが間違っているか、あるいは同じこと指していたり、何かしらの関連性があって途中が抜けている等の場合、質問を追加・修正してみてください。また対象のソースコードを提示して、そのどの部分なのかといった情報も追記してください。こちらのヘルプ記事を参考に。良い質問をするには？, 再現可能な短いサンプルコードの書き方

ちなみにこんなリポジトリが参考になるかもしれませんね。linouk23/youtube_uploader_selenium

「PythonとSeleniumでYouTubeに動画を自動アップロードするスクリプト」とはどういったものでしょうか？「要素をうまく取得できません。」とは具体的には何かエラーが発生しているのでしょうか？それとも別の現象が発生しているのでしょうか？またYouTubeにseleniumでアクセスするのは利用規約上問題のない行為でしょうか？
